# terraform apply error alreadyExists on untouched resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform

I am starting a new terraform project, following the official guide:

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/gke?in=terraform/kubernetes&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS&_ga=2.91746777.2118895439.1637849824-960084622.1637849824

I have managed to get it to run. (I am running it as part of a google cloud build task triggered on commit)

However, if i change something in a resource (eg i replaced "gke_num_nodes" default from 2 to 1), when i run `terraform apply` again  this is what I get:

```
Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + kubernetes_cluster_host = (known after apply)
  + kubernetes_cluster_name = "workspace-auto-gke"
  + project_id              = "workspace-auto"
  + region                  = "europe-west4"
google_compute_network.vpc: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/workspace-auto/global/networks/workspace-auto-vpc' already exists, alreadyExists
│ 
│   with google_compute_network.vpc,
│   on vpc.tf line 15, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc":
│   15: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
│ 
╵
```

Is there a way to get it to not try to recreate existing untouched resources?

My `cloudbuild.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "hashicorp/terraform",
      "entrypoint": "/bin/sh",
      "args": [
        "./cloudbuild/prepare-terraform.sh"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "logsBucket": "gs://my-bucket/logdir",
  "serviceAccount": "projects/my-proj/serviceAccounts/my-service-account@my-proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

with `prepare-terraform.sh` being simply

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terraform state needs to be stored where it's accessible by all the builds. For example in a google cloud bucket as seen here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/gcs.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Terraform to create resources, do **NOT** modify them outside of Terraform.

If you change something manually, Terraform will attempt to put it back the way the HCL declares it and the way that Terraform saved it.

This is called **declarative**. You are trying to make Terraform dynamic which defeats using Terraform in the first place.

Comment: The modification i did was inside  the terraform files not outside.
Simply when i run the terraform plan  / apply it will try to create everything from scratch regardless even if it was unchanged and cause the error